# Zeek Workers cannot communicate with Zeek Proxy/manager

Tags: networking, zeek

I set up a small zeek cluster and had it working fine. Here's my rough setup:

```
Proxy/Manager/Logger - 192.168.1.10
Worker-1 - 192.168.1.10 (em1)
Worker-2 - 192.168.1.15 (em1)
Worker-3 - 192.168.1.15 (p1p1)
Worker-4 - 192.168.1.15 (p1p2)
Worker-5 - 192.168.1.16 (em1)
Worker-6 - 192.168.1.16 (p1p1)
Worker-7 - 192.168.1.16 (p1p2)
```

Everything was going swell. However, now nothing gets brokered except for worker-1 which is local to the proxy/manager/logger. I can do deploy, start, and stop workers through zeekctl. However, peerstatus hangs indefinitely when checking a remote worker.

I've even set up a new cluster on brand new systems starting from scratch with the same issues. This leads me to believe it's in the network but I can't figure out for the life of me what it could be. I know this is vague but does anyone have at least some troubleshooting ideas for me to try?

Let me know what else I can give you. I appreciate any kind of help you can send my way!

Comment: Do you have the firewall enabled on these machines?  That's the most problem I've seen with multi host clusters like this.

Comment: I do but nothing in the config changed when things suddenly stopped working. Is the communication for start/stop/deploy different than the transfer of logs? Also, correct me if I'm wrong but the worker should be creating more than just stderr and stdout logs right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seth Hall nailed it. I messed up the rules without knowing. Thankfully an easy fix. Thanks.